# I have a class that is derived from a QList object. I have used for loops, I keep getting the error that list is not declared in the scope

Tags: c++, pointers, qt

I have a class that is derived from a QList object. I have used for loops, I keep getting the error that list is not declared in the scope

```
#include "AssetList.h"
#include "Asset.h"


AssetList::AssetList(QObject *parent){
}

AssetList::~AssetList(){
    qDeleteAll(*this);
    clear();
}

bool AssetList::addAsset(Asset *a){
    int duplicate;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        if (list.at(i) == a)
            duplicate = 0;
        else if (list.at(i) != a)
            duplicate = 1;
    }

    if (duplicate == 0)
        return false;
    else if (duplicate == 1)
        return true;
}

Asset* AssetList::findAsset(QString des){
    Asset* found;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if (list.at(i).description == des)
            found = list.at(i);
        else
            found = NULL;
    }

    return found;
}

double AssetList::totalValue(QString typ){
    double totalValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if (list.at(i).type == typ)
            totalValue += list.at(i).value();
        else
            totalValue = totalValue;
    }

    return totalValue;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue.  It may be on-topic for other SE sites but does not provide enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking others to debug a code dump.

Comment: Why did you derive from `QList` again?

Comment: Show us `AssetList.h`

Comment: Your impl of findAsset() is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@ Jefffrey, I derived the AssetList class from QList, because AssetList is actually derived from QList.

**Here is AssetList.h if it will help:**

```
#ifndef ASSETLIST_H
#define ASSETLIST_H

#include "Asset.h"

#include <QList>

class AssetList: public QList<Asset*>{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AssetList(QObject *parent = 0);

    ~AssetList();

    bool addAsset(Asset* a);

    Asset* findAsset(QString des);

    double totalValue(QString typ);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // ASSETLIST_H
```